# convert css to jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this css:

```
@media only screen and (max-height: 620px) {
#howto img {
    margin-left:150px;
}
.boilerplate {
    text-align:right;
}
.footer .boilerplate .links {
    float:right;
}
.footer {
    text-align:right !important;
}
```

}

and I want to do this css with jQuery. How can I do it?

Comment: i cant explain why, i just need to do it

Comment: This question does make some sense since some CMS's strip out <style> tags when placed in the editor but don't strip javascript/jQuery. If you don't have access to change the code as a developer, sometimes the only way to make a page look right is to use a jQuery css workaround...granted it's not at all a good idea to do consistently. It's best to have a developer with access make the style changes to the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("document").ready(function(){  
    if ($(window).width() <= 620) {
      $("#howto img").css("margin-left", "150");
      $(".boilerplate").css("text-align", "right");
      $(".footer .boilerplate .links").css("float", "right");
      $(".footer").css("text-align", "right");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".boilerplate").css("text-align","right");
});
```

But you must then make every style in jquery.
Another possibility would be to make the styles completely database driven and loop through.

Comment: yes, i know that but how to do this `@media only screen and (max-height: 620px) {` ?

Comment: you don't need to do it over media. In jquery you can get the window sizes directly. You set it then in an if

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function(){  
    if ($(window).width() <= 620) {
      $("#howto img").css("margin-left", "150");
      $(".boilerplate").css("text-align", "right");
      $(".footer .boilerplate .links").css("float", "right");
      $(".footer").css("text-align", "right");
    }else{    /*Asuming you didn't have any inline style before*/
         $('#howto img,.boilerplate,.footer,.footer .boilerplate .links').removeAttr('style'); 
         /*To restore de original styles*/
    }
});
```

Comment: This way it will be applied everytime the window is resized. not only on document.ready

Comment: But if you do not need support for older browsers i just don't understand why you need to do this in Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried [beansoup](http://www.beansoup.de/csstoscript.php)? They have a nice CSS to jQuery converter.

Sometimes, there are some problems with the conversions, but most of them are great.